# How to loop through array of objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object like this:

```
{
"batman":[{"applicantSkillID":"htl2","rating":3,"applicantInterviewerID":"usr1","applicantInterviewerName":"batman","applicantSkillName":"HTML"},
{"applicantSkillID":"cs43","rating":5,"applicantInterviewerID":"usr1","applicantInterviewerName":"batman","applicantSkillName":"css"}],

"Superman":[{"applicantSkillID":"ht12","rating":3,"applicantInterviewerID":"usr2","applicantInterviewerName":"Superman","applicantSkillName":"HTML"},
{"applicantSkillID":"cs43","rating":3,"applicantInterviewerID":"usr2","applicantInterviewerName":"Superman","applicantSkillName":"css"}]
}
```

Now I am trying to display data `applicantInterviewerName` wise (Batman's rating, Superman's rating etc..)

for only one  `applicantInterviewerName` i can able to do it by taking the first object index like this:

```
<tbody class="table text-left boxShade displayTable">
    <tr ng-repeat="feedBack in c.data.interviewerFeedback">
        <td class="skillName" id="{{feedBack.applicantSkillID}}"> {{feedBack.applicantSkillName}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="inputRangeDiv">
                <input class="inputRangeInputSlilder"
                   ng-init="skillScoreForm.skill[feedBack.applicantSkillID] = feedBack.rating"
                   ng-model="skillScoreForm.skill[feedBack.applicantSkillID]"
                   value="0"  
                   oninput="skillOutput.value = skillInput.value"
                   id='skillInput' type="range"
                   min="0" max="5"  ng-disabled="true" />

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="inlineFlex">
                <output id="skillOutput" class="output">{{feedBack.rating}}</output>
                <p class="applicantCutoffOutputSufixModalTable">/5</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can i do it for all i think i am sure i need to use two `ng-repeats` one for  `applicantInterviewerName`  and one for `skills` but not getting idea to how to acheive it.?

Comment: yes you need two ng-repeat. and if you always have one object you dont need an ng-repeat

Comment: Would you mind creating a plunkr? i'll take it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var obj = {
 "batman": [{
   "applicantSkillID": "htl2",
   "rating": 3,
   "applicantInterviewerID": "usr1",
   "applicantInterviewerName": "batman",
   "applicantSkillName": "HTML"
  },
  {
   "applicantSkillID": "cs43",
   "rating": 5,
   "applicantInterviewerID": "usr1",
   "applicantInterviewerName": "batman",
   "applicantSkillName": "css"
  }
 ],

 "Superman": [{
   "applicantSkillID": "ht12",
   "rating": 3,
   "applicantInterviewerID": "usr2",
   "applicantInterviewerName": "Superman",
   "applicantSkillName": "HTML"
  },
  {
   "applicantSkillID": "cs43",
   "rating": 3,
   "applicantInterviewerID": "usr2",
   "applicantInterviewerName": "Superman",
   "applicantSkillName": "css"
  }
 ]
};

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = obj;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in items">
      <div ng-repeat="data in items[key]">
        <span>Name : </span>{{data.applicantInterviewerName}} , <span>Rating : </span>{{data.rating}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```